# How to retrieve full relationships from an item that has a relationship with itself?

Tags: laravel

I have comments and replies to those comments and I want to bring the full relationships. I want to bring all the comment relationships when calling the replies. It's kinda confusing so let me show that I mean with actual data.

This is the model

```
class ForumReply extends Model
{
    protected $fillable = [
        'user_id',
        'bulletin_id',
        'comment',
        'anonymous'
    ];

    public $timestamps = true;

    public function discussionForum()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo(DiscussionForum::class);
    }

    public function user()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo(User::class);
    }

    public function replies()
    {
        return $this->hasMany(ForumReply::class, 'parent_id');
    }
}
```

This is the function in the controller

```
public function show($id)
{
    $forum = DiscussionForum::findOrFail($id)
        ->with('comments', 'user')->first();
    $comment = ForumReply::with('discussionForum', 'user', 'replies')
        ->where('discussion_forum_id', $forum->id)
        ->orderByDesc('comment_time')->get();

    return Inertia::render('Forum/View.vue', [
        'forum' => $forum,
        'comments' => $comment
    ]);
}
```

This is the data I get in the vue for the `$comment` query, as you can see the replies part has very little information, in order to display it as I want I need more information, like the user info for the person who replied not just the person with the parent comment.

```
{ 
   "id":4,
   "user_id":41,
   "discussion_forum_id":1,
   "parent_id":null,
   "comment":"adsfasdf asdf asdfa sdf ",
   "comment_time":"2019-12-03 11:25:00",
   "created_at":null,
   "updated_at":null,
   "discussion_forum":{ 
      "id":1,
      "theme":"asdfa",
      "description":"asdffghjluui",
      "user_id":1,
      "anonymous":0,
      "start_date":"2019-11-24 06:00:00",
      "end_date":"2019-12-30 06:00:00",
      "created_at":"2019-11-27 13:21:03",
      "updated_at":"2019-11-27 13:21:03"
   },
   "user":{ 
      "id":41,
      "name":"Isadora Felix",
      "card":"12346",
      "scard":"97531",
      "user_type_id":4,
      "email":"i@email.com",
      "created_at":"2019-12-03 10:09:26",
      "updated_at":"2019-12-03 10:09:26"
   },
   "replies":[ 
      { 
         "id":6,
         "user_id":39,
         "discussion_forum_id":1,
         "parent_id":4,
         "comment":"not agreeing",
         "comment_time":"2019-12-03 11:26:01",
         "created_at":null,
         "updated_at":null
      }
   ]
}
```

Is there another way to bring this information in a way where I can get the information on the reply just as if it was a parent comment? Or is there a better way to approach this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can load nested relationships with the dot notation.
For example:

```php
$forum = DiscussionForum::with(['user', 'comment' => function ($query) {
    return $query->orderByDesc('comment_time');
}, 'comment.user', 'comments.replies.user'])->findOrFail($id);
```

This code will load the discussion forum with the user and comments with their authors. Then for each comment it also retrives its replies with their respective authors.

**Side note**: Keep in mind that `findOrFail($id)` actually executes a query. If you then call `->with(...)->first()` you are performing a second query on the database.
You can instead start with `::with(...)` method and then call `->findOrFail($id)`.

Comment: So I should do instead `$forum = DiscussionForum::with('comments.replies.user', 'user', 'comments.user')->findOrFail($id);` ?

Comment: Exactly. I also updated my answer to include the descending ordering on the comments' creation time that should work as well

Answer (score 1):

If you know you will never want to access the ForumReply without it's user you can add the user to the protected "with" attribute so it will always be appended with every model of this type

```
class ForumReply extends Model
{
   protected $with = ['user'];
}
```

This will save you the code to including the user and will also help with the next part

Unless you limit ForumReplies to only have a single reply to them, you will have to consider nesting level on the relationship. However there is an easy fix for this, make your relationship recursive.

```
public function replies()
{
  return $this->hasMany(ForumReply::class, 'parent_id')->with('replies');
}
```

The combination of those two changes will load all replies to a reply, even if they are replying to another reply, and attach the user to each one.